# PHP xls export from mysql with multiple input and output

Tags: php, mysql, input, export, xls

I want to export multiple data in to xls. The user can input a id (13,42,192) and the script write xls.

```
if(isset($_POST['download_xls'])) {

$filename = 'id_'.$id.'_'.$db_tabel.'_'.date('d-m-Y_H-i',time());

$id_suche = explode(",", str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['id_suche']));

header("Content-Type: application/xls; charset=utf-8");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

print("id\tlayout\tmenge\tname\tvorname\tlieferadresse\tbesteller_name\tbesteller_email\tmitteilung");
print("\n");

foreach ($id_suche as $tmp_id) {

    $query = "SELECT id, layout, menge, name, vorname, lieferadresse, besteller_name, besteller_email, mitteilung FROM be_bestellungen WHERE id = ".$tmp_id;

    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

    $sep = "\t";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

        $schema_insert = "";

        for($j=0; $j < mysql_num_fields($result); $j++) {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }        


        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";


        print(trim($schema_insert));

        die;

    }   
}
```

}

the script write only 1 data in xls. if i write one id in the input field no resulte.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use the `mysli_*` class

And the answer to your question:

Remove the `die();` in your while loop

If you want to go to the next iteration in the loop use `continue;`

If you want to break the loop use `break;`

php.net is your best friend ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php))